# python flask json response embed url for clickable redirect

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

My flask Restful API currently provides a get response

`$ curl https://endpoint/bucket/blahhh
{"response": {"items": ["item1"], "id": "blahhh", "time": 1544638988174, "user": "mafia"}}`

Can I make the "items" list items to dynamically redirect to different endpoint "https://endpoint/item/item1" ON-CLICK using flask? (kind of like "href")

Note that the response here is plain JSON, there are no templates here.

If the question has been asked already, please direct me towards it..

Comment: how do you click on JSON?

Comment: @JacobIRR hmm, makes sense, so the only way is to provide an entire link in the JSON response?

Comment: Yes, you could return a link, and in order to do that, it would be helpful to see the code that generates this JSON response. This will allow people to help advise on constructing the link(s)

Comment: If you want the consumer of this JSON payload to receive links, you can return the items as links instead (or as objects with a 'link' key). To make them clickable (presumably in a browser) would be the job of the consumer/client - there should be code on that side to construct an html link.

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to use url_for() of flask

Comment: It is always helpful add some explanation and example to your answer, to make it more clear and understandable. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.